# LibreOffice small resolution 4K screen

Tags: libreoffice, display-resolution

All programs, **except LibreOffice**, make it easy to adjust the resolution for my 4K screen. What should I do to adjust LibreOffice resolution?

[image]

Comment: Does `sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3` help? Are you using a snap version of Libreoffice? If so, switch to the apt version and check if the issue is fixed. You can also use fractional scaling in display settings.

Comment: I disable, en destroyed all snaps. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archisman Panigrahi has solved the problem. `sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)